# How can i select element in selenium webdriver by part of ID.

Tags: selenium, find, webdriver

I have a td element with ID like "a:2:3:d:", and when i want to select it by id, my webdriver can not find it. Is there a way to search by part of ID, because I think, that the problem is at last ":" in the identifier.

Comment: yes, it is. The char before the last ":" is changing.

Comment: You need to be much more clear about stating the problem. See this for help: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to confirm that this really is the problem, and it's not just that the page isn't fully loaded, or is loaded asynchronously. I don't see any particular reason why Selenium should care about the trailing ":".

**Update:** From the comments, it's much more likely that the dynamic id that is the problem, but the solution is the same either way:

To find an element by partial id, you can use xpath. If you were trying to find a `div` by partial id, for example:

```
//div[contains(@id, 'a:2:3')]
```

You don't say what language you are using, but in python, this would be used as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'a:2:3')]")
```

and in Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@id, 'a:2:3')]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Java

```
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[id*='a:2:3']"));
```

The above code gets the element of TD which starts with a:2:3 as we use * in the css Selector.

XPath is more powerful and can be sometimes difficult to understand. CSS Selector is easy.

Comment: And the language is JAVA. Sorry, that i didn't mention it before.

Comment: I just can not find it. It throws exception, the actual code is :

Comment: "wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementtobeclickable(By.cssSelector("td[id*='a:2:3']"))).Click();

Comment: just a seccond to run it again and i will write it

Comment: "no such element" at browser.FindElement and
"timed out after 15 seconds waiting" for wait.until.
But I can see. that the element is displayed.
It is strange, but true.

Comment: Try driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("td[id*='a:2:3']")).get(0)

Comment: When I try this, I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method get(int) is undefined for the type WebElement"

Comment: findElements should be used instead of findElement